# Changing value of aura:attribute on .cmp page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

wondering if this statement would ever work.

I decalred attribute at top of page

```
<aura:attribute name="groupTracker" type="String"/>
```

and on an aura:if i wish to set the following

```
<aura:set attribute="{!v.groupTracker}" value="{!stand.Audit__r.Group__c}"/>
```

If this is not possible, looking for any kind of variable handling I may be able to use in the .cmp

Edit: 2017-03-08
The whole reason for the above was to build a dynamic datatable in .cmp, So after many futile attempted I found the above extremely challenging and the aura:set does not assign a direct value it works more on attributes of objects...(something like that). My solution in the end was handling my Objects in the controller and rebuilding the datatable in a neat layout as below.

```
Group     Name     ID     Subject

T01       
          Tan01    SS2    TanAndSata
          Tan02    SS3    Tan2Sata3
T02       
          SamIs    Not    AtHome
          Test1    22     theEnd
```

For now thats the best I can do :( quite sad but hopefully as I learn ill maybe update with a better solution.